# xml validation XSD with errors reject

Tags: java, xml, scala, xsd

I'm using this method to validate XML:

```
@param :

    - Fs_Path_Xsd : XSD File path
    - hadoopConfiguration : hadoop Conf
    - XML_Path_File : Xml File path

 @return :
     - (number error, error message)**
```

Function to validate XML with an XSD:

```
  def XmlXsdValidate(Fs_Path_Xsd: String, hadoopConfiguration: Configuration, XML_Path_File: String): ArrayBuffer[(Int, String)] = {

    try {
      // schema from XSD  
      @transient lazy val schema = {
        val factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI)
        val Fs_Path_Xsd_file = new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(Fs_Path_Xsd)
        val File_Fs_Path_Xsd = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration).open(Fs_Path_Xsd_file)
        val schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(File_Fs_Path_Xsd))
        schema
      }

      // parseur XML
      @transient lazy val saxParser = {
        val f = SAXParserFactory.newInstance()
        f.setNamespaceAware(true)
        f.setSchema(schema)
        f.newSAXParser()
      }

      var listexceptions = ArrayBuffer[SAXParseException]()

      @transient lazy val handler = new DefaultHandler() {
        override def error(ex: SAXParseException) {
          listexceptions += ex
        }

        override def warning(ex: SAXParseException) {
          listexceptions += ex
        }

        override def fatalError(ex: SAXParseException) {
          listexceptions += ex
        }
      }

      //recuperation XML File 
      val File_Fs_Path_File = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(hadoopConfiguration).open(new Path(XML_Path_File))
      //Xml validate from XSD
      saxParser.parse(File_Fs_Path_File, handler)

      var i = 0

      var exceptions = ArrayBuffer[(Int, String)]()

      if (listexceptions.size > 0) {
        exceptions = listexceptions.map { ex =>
          i += 1
          (i, "Error at Line: " + ex.getLineNumber + " Column: " + ex.getColumnNumber + " in " + XML_Path_File + "  Message: " + ex.getMessage)
        }

      } else {
        exceptions = ArrayBuffer((0, "message valid"))
      }

      return exceptions
    } catch {
      case t: Throwable =>
        t.printStackTrace() // TODO: handle error

        return null
    }
  }
```

Any ideas of how I could handle the wrong tags that I want to reject?

Comment: There's an example of validating XML with an XSD in Scala on the scala-xml wiki https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/wiki/XML-validation